# How do I make a script activate an enabled when stepping on a block? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

## *How do I make it so that when I step on a block, the enabled of the script in the Startergui folder is activated, but when I stop stepping on it, the enabled is turned off again?*

*For example, I want that when I step on the block called "PartOne" the enabled of a script in starterGui called "First Person" is activated and when I stop stepping on this the enabled of the script is deactivated but I want it to only be activated with the players and no NPC or blocks*

## **Sorry if this is written wrong but I'm using Google Translate because I don't know English.**

I was trying to make a script run by touching a block.

Comment: See https://create.roblox.com/docs/tutorials/scripting/basic-scripting/intro-to-scripting

Answer (score 0):

```js
local Players,part,tab=game:GetService"Players",script.Parent,{}
local function onPlayerAdded(player)
    table.insert(tab,player.Name)
    table.insert(tab,{})
end;Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)
for _,v in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers())do onPlayerAdded(v)end
part.Touched:Connect(function(part)
    local player=Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
    if player then
        local tab=tab[table.find(tab,player.Name)+1]
        local v=table.find(tab,part)
        table.insert(tab,part)
        player.PlayerGui["First Person"].Enabled=true
    end
end)
part.TouchEnded:Connect(function(part)
    local player=Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
    if player then
        local tab=tab[table.find(tab,player.Name)+1]
        table.remove(tab,table.find(tab,part))
        wait(.1)
        if #tab==0 then
            player.PlayerGui["First Person"].Enabled=false
        end
    end
end)
Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local i=table.find(tab,player.Name)
    table.remove(tab,i)
    table.remove(tab,i)
end)
```